# Change path to different versions on an executable for currenct session in linux BASH

Tags: bash

I need to easy change path to an executable in bash *without* changing the name of the binary (e.g. there might be some other script/process that assumes a binary exists on PATH called exactly the name of the binary). For the sake of the example below lets say the executable is called: `EXECUTABLE`.

Right now I have:

**~/.bashrc**

```
e11() {
  export EXECUTABLE="/home/user/tools/EXECUTABLE-1.1.0/"
  export PATH=$EXECUTABLE:$PATH
}
export -f e11

e19() {
  export EXECUTABLE="/home/user/tools/EXECUTABLE-1.9.0/"
  export PATH=$EXECUTABLE:$PATH
}
export -f e19
```

The above works. Meaning in a terminal I can just type `e11` or `e19` so switch between the different version of the `EXECUTABLE`. But if I need a few more versions the list starts to grow. Are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes just pass the $var instead e.g.

```
myapp() {
  export EXECUTABLE="/home/user/tools/EXECUTABLE-${1}/"
}

myapp "$1"
echo $EXECUTABLE
```

output:

```
$ bash 1.sh 1.1
/home/user/tools/EXECUTABLE-1.1/
$ bash 1.sh 1.2
/home/user/tools/EXECUTABLE-1.2/
$ bash 1.sh whatevervalueiput
/home/user/tools/EXECUTABLE-whatevervalueiput/
```

edit: I'd be careful about always appending to $PATH though - that's a different problem for you to tackle

Comment: Yes considered a parameter as well but then I need to remember valid input - would like to keep it as fool proof as possible :-) Hm probably not better way to do it then

Comment: I don't see what the difference is when e11 e19 etc are also 'valid input' values you need to remember - your $PATH: is your biggest issue anyway. try it now type e11 and e19 then echo $PATH

Comment: I can tab/autocomplete on e11 and e19 without having to remember what it accepts of input. echo $PATH looks fine, whatever I run last gets added to the top of my PATH as expected for the current session.